# Laravel 5.1 Cashier - Adds customer but without info

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I am using Laravel 5.1 trying to set it up with Stripe using [Cashier](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/billing).

I am using a custom button to execute the javascript (using Angular):

```
$scope.subscribe = function(plan){

            var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
                key: 'pk_test_*************',
                image: '/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png',
                locale: 'auto',
                token: function(token) {
                  // Use the token to create the charge with a server-side script.
                  // You can access the token ID with `token.id`
                    var data = 'stripeToken=' + token.id;
                    $http.post("/createSubscription", data).success(function(data, status) {
                        console.log(data);
                    });
                }
            });

            handler.open({
                  name: 'basic',
                  description: 'basic monthly $100',
                  currency: "usd",
                  amount: 10000
            });

            $(window).on('popstate', function() {
                handler.close();
            });

        };
```

And in my Laravel code I have:

```
public function createSubscription(Request $request)
{
    $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();

    $token = Input::get('stripeToken');

    $user->subscription("basic_plan")->create($token);

    return 'test';
}
```

But I keep getting an error saying "this customer has no attached payment source".

The returned token at this line:

```
    token: function(token) {
    ...
```

Does contain the users email, card info (+ card token), and stripe token. But when I check my Stripe dashboard, a customer is added *without* any data (no card, no email and not set up with the subscription).

I am trying to create customers with a subscription plan via this form.

(I do have the Billable trait set up and included in the controller)

Comment: Solved it. Really dumb - I wasn't posting credit card info with the initial submission that creates a customer (or charge).